# Element mul in PBC Library

Tags: c

I have this code, that uses PBC Library:

```
element_t pk, pk_temp;

element_init_G2(pk, pairing);
element_init_G2(pk_temp, pairing);
element_init_Zr(ci, pairing);

element_pow_zn(pk_temp, pk_temp, ci);
element_set1(pk);
element_add(pk, pk, pk);

element_mul_zn(pk, pk, pk_temp);
```

When I run this program(ci has a value from earlier calculations), this is the output that I get :

```
pk_temp
[116278406325033872100813200201193617766578695181932793603160637278854742066192092884782310233584512588249536578523628847229234460071209045611450183651531, 2021454548422679707182594138446448992982063147118097540714810473185383559710078393323207940613550542761869670939719707936590719813436809712827363459486303]
ci
557018308384393102708847545615423648196401851115

After pk_temp^ci
pk_temp
[108256843552655255908398113161102639677286937761571877242159361199581616450078081163742350174144405610156719380747507503987165257266343606269839543701390, 315460454942637140235438889718432767280220200962474346118962958364243678526968323118117335000004382683381426774251553048778733132443252812268528626451784]

After pk = pk + pk
pk
0

After pk = pk * pk_temp
pk
O
```

**UPDATE**
If pk is initialized as an element in Zr, the addition works.

Comment: It is generally not a good idea to use the same variable as both argument and result for an operation - both because it is not clean code, but also because it might cause the value of the parameter to be overwritten because it is used by the function. I don't know if "PBC" does this, but the symptoms are consistent with this explanation.

Comment: @HenrickHellström The error occurred only at that line. The pow operation for pk_temp did not show any similar behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
element_mul_zn(pk, pk, pk_temp);
```

But in fact, your pk_temp is in G2 rather than Zn.

See the definition in include/pbc_field.h

```
static inline void element_mul_zn(element_t c, element_t a, element_t z) {
  mpz_t z0; 
  PBC_ASSERT_MATCH2(c, a); 
  //TODO: check z->field is Zn
  mpz_init(z0);
  element_to_mpz(z0, z); 
  element_mul_mpz(c, a, z0);
  mpz_clear(z0);
}
```

The code does not check if `z->field` is `Zn` and will just converts `G2` to `mpz`.
It does not make sense if you want to convert `G2` to `mpz`, and `element_to_mpz` just gives you 0.

Comment: Ok. I tried `element_mul(pk, pk, pk_temp);` The value of pk is non-zero. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: Yeah, your answer explains why I got such an output

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which type of pairing do you use, so I suppose you use type A pairing. The function

```
element_set1(pk);
```

sets pk to *O*, the point at infinity, since pk is an element of G2. So the result should look like this

```
element_set1(pk);
pk = O

After pk=pk+pk
pk = O

After pk = pk * pk_temp
pk
O
```

the result of pk*pk_temp is *O* because for all scalar number c,  *O* = c * *O*.

Answer (score 0):

We generally do not accept code-review questions here; perhaps stackexchange (not crypto) would be better.

On the other hand, I do notice that you do:

```
element_set1(pk);
```

Would that set pk to 1?  If so, why would it be surprising that pk would be set to 2 after you add pk to itself?

Comment: That is expected. But the unexpected part is where pk * pk_temp returns 0

Comment: Ok, should I post this question instead in stackoverflow?

Comment: @Ajoy: actually, it's cleaner if one of the moderators migrates it (rather than having you enter a duplicate question).  I've already flagged it for migration.